# How to address (if at all) OPs who try to sneak-edit?

Tags: discussion, questions

Every once in a while I come across a situation [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37899473/how-to-break-the-y-axis-in-manhattan-plot-so-that-a-given-range-of-p-values-are?noredirect=1#comment63253473_37899473) where an OP makes a mistake in their example code, gets called out, then edits it (not realizing the edit history is visible) and replies to the comments about the bug in their code that they have no idea what that person is talking about and their code works just fine.

I don't really care that much, but still, it's kind of rude and sneaky.

For instance, the OP in the linked question above asked for help with a plot, giving nice example code... except the code was broken. I commented the errors it gave and speculated that he was missing a `,` or `)` somewhere. He added the missing `)` then told me it works fine for him and he has no idea what I'm talking about.

Should we bother saying anything in this situation? Should we downvote? Or just let it go?

Comment: Meh, move on. As long as it's not invalidating an answer, let them feel smart.

Comment: @Kyll Yea that's probably best I guess, thanks

Comment: I'd argue that letting them know that their change is visible makes it less likely that they'll annoy other folks the same way in the future. That can be as simple as a "FYI".

Comment: way to put that persons post on blast, haha

Comment: @Paul OP is original poster, usually referred to as Asker on this site.

Comment: He has 11 downvotes now :_)

Comment: Bloody meta-effect :(

Comment: (Given that the comments are now deleted, I can't see for myself) Are you sure that he was being "sneaky"? If someone finds a typo in my code and points it out, it's not unheard-of for me to fix it and say "huh what typo I don't see what you mean nope no typos there nuh-uh *shifty eyes*"

Comment: @QPaysTaxes True but then I would expect at least a smiley or some other indicator of irony.

Comment: I see the `)` in the edit history but I don't see any other changes. Yet your comment mentions two errors. How was the other one resolved?

Comment: I updated the post, please consider re-opening and/or removing your downvotes

Comment: It didn't need calling out on here, you've just killed the question. @zx8754 Good effort though to revive it, up-voted.

Comment: @zx8754: I am not sure I agree with your edit to that question. Haven't we long said that meta-commentary is confusing for readers who don't care about the Meta Effect, or who would be confused that the "original question" is not front and centre? I proposed that the edit/task/note is merged in transparently, for the benefit of future readers (though I will leave it to you, so as not to overwrite your changes).

Comment: @halfer I thought I marked it clearly as "Edit" and "Original Post", let me know what is the "right" way of edit, or feel free to update.

Comment: @zx8754: most of this is a matter of opinion, but in general I think questions should have Edit/Update sections at the end, if at all. Consider the new reader: if they do not know what "meta effect" is they may skip to a new question, since they may think that it's domain knowledge they don't have (and I'd wager less than 5% of the readership know what this is). Then they might wonder why blocks of the question have been exploded outside of the "real question", which to me spoils the Q&A flow for a reader some months from now.

Comment: @awendt Fair enough. Like I said, I can't see the comments; I just thought it was worth pointing out that it could have been a joke which just missed.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It is really up to any user how to handle feedback. You'll find several types of responses:

- None at all
- Polite
- Rude
- Down playing
- Sheepish
- Offensive
- Denial

Some individuals might learn over time that both the truth and a form of politeness are the preferred/social accepted ways to interact with others. I'm happy with being rude now and then.

As a commentator, it is best to focus on the issue in the post and make sure those get fixed, no matter how you are treated. If you can fix it yourself and the OP shows no signs of taking feedback seriously, please edit the post. If you can't fix the post, make sure it is clear in a comment what needs to be edited. Before you move on, clean-up the comments you deem no longer needed and flag what is not constructive, chatty or rude.

Comment: This is a brilliant answer and explanation of the types of feedback, thanks.

Comment: Now let me categorize the *people* corresponding to each type of response ... *\*--> gets flagged\**

Comment: *clean-up the comments you deem no longer needed* If they're not your comments, you can use the "obsolete" flag. That's what the OP should have done if they had the privilege.

Comment: What does "*sheepish*" mean?

Comment: @TomášZato Like a Sheep: *Meh*

Comment: @TomášZato: Someone who apologizes (too much for the liking of other participants in the conversation) is being sheepish.

Comment: @TomášZato Sheepish means embarrassed.

Comment: @rene Interesting--I've always thought of "meh" as more commonly an expression of a devil-may-care attitude than a sheepish one.

Comment: "Devil-may-care" indicates an unusual lack of concern.  "Meh" indicates a perfectly ordinary lack of concern.  The closest formal English synonym is probably "who cares?"

Comment: You forgot entitled :)

Comment: You forgot "owning up to it and acknowledging one's shortcomings". It does happen, if entirely too rarely.

Comment: @Grant — But if that's the case, the typo is the entire issue and fixing it solves the problem, you should vote to close as off-topic "simple typographical error" as was done with the question in question.  The question is of no value to future visitors.

Comment: I updated the post, please consider re-opening and/or removing your downvotes.

Comment: @zx8754 which down votes? Those 7 on your question?

Comment: @rene No, not this meta post, I meant in the linked post. Which is now edited and re-opened. Sorry, this comment was directed to downvoters.

Comment: @zx8754 That question on main is lost, I doubt anyone will re-visit and reverse their votes ...

Comment: @rene Thanks, I realise that, but still hoping for SO magic to happen, I did my bit. I had similar request for plotting, we ended up doing it manually, hence my edit efforts, hoping it will be useful for future readers.

Comment: Sure @zx8754 thanks for your effort, you're not to blame.

Answer (score 11):

If it only invalidates a comment, I just remove the comment.  Life's too short to worry about it.

If it invalidates an answer without noting the edit in the text of the question, I may downvote and vote to close, on the basis that questions trying to address two unrelated issues are too broad and a new question should have been asked instead.

Answer (score 5):

There could be two situations:

**1. Someone comments and the asker updates the question** (This is what the linked question currently looks like to me).

In this case I might add a comment to clarify that the problem has been solved, in order to avoid confusion for future readers.

**2. Someone comments, the asker updates the question and replies that nothing is wrong**

In this case it is most important that you don't get rude yourself. That being said, I am not a great fan of ignoring this as it can confuse or demoralize the person who tried to help. As such I would reply as such:

> His comment referred to the original question, after the current edit this issue indeed no longer relevant.

Answer (score 2):

There's one other thing you haven't considered. The user, instead of copy/pasting his code over, typed it out and missed a `,` or some other items. I know I've been guilty of that fact for a one-liner. I just shrug and look to see what else could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

it depends. if the OP is asking "what's wrong with this code" and the answer is inside that edit, I'd call them on it - they should update properly to reflect that they answered their question. if the edit is entirely irrelevant to the question at hand, just let it go.